# deleting loops to increase efficiency in python

Tags: python, performance, loops

How do I make this more efficient?  I feel like I should be able to do this without looping through the entire dataframe.  Basically I have to split the column `CollectType`, into multiple columns depending on the the value in column `SSampleCode`.

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
  if df.SSampleCode[i]=='Rock':
     df.R_SampleType[i]=df.CollectType[i]
  elif df.SSampleCode[i]=='Soil':
     df.S_SampleType[i]=df.CollectType[i]
  elif df.SSampleCode[i]=='Pan Con':
     df.PC_SampleType[i]=df.CollectType[i]
  elif df.SSampleCode[i]=='Silt':
     df.SS_SampleType[i]=df.CollectType[i]
```

Comment: You should rethink the data structure `df`, whatever that is...  It has four array fields, but for every value of `i`, 3 out of the 4 array values are undefined.  Something isn't right there. It looks like you might want a single array of 2-tuples containing a `CollectType` and a string with one of the four tag values.

Comment: You can use a dictionary where the keys are the SSampleCode values, and the dictionary values are the column name to place the CollectType in.  As it is your assignment, you take it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using masks (vectorial approach):

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
  if df.SSampleCode[i]=='Rock':
     df.R_SampleType[i]=df.CollectType[i]
```

will be

```
mask = df.SSampleCode=='Rock'
df.R_SampleType[mask] = df.CollectType[mask]
```

This will give you a good perf improvement.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I thought was possible, I just am too new to python to know the syntax.